# Rotated Div at the end of HTML table

Tags: html, css, rotation, alignment

What I thought would be a seemingly trivial task has taken way longer than I expected and still not close to resolving it. I have a HTML table which will contain some data. Just to the right of the table, I want to display a rotated div with some text in, similar to this:[image]

I've managed to create the table how i'd like it, but I cant for the life of me get the "Reporting" div aligned at the side of the table.

Here is my code attempt so far, can anyone provide me with any pointers to achieve my goal?

```css
.container {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: x-large;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.tableCont {
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

table td {
  /*border-radius: 15px;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

table td.colFY {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #887870;
}

table td.norm {
  background-color: #B8B8B8;
  color: #082860;
}
div {
  display:inline;
}
.side {
  background: #B8B8B8;
  bottom:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="tableCont">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class='colFY'>FY18</td>
                <td class='norm'>Subject 1</td>
                <td class='norm' data-title='HR Dashboard'>Subject 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='colFY'>FY19</td>
                <td class='norm'>Subject 3</td>
                <td class='norm'>Subject 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='colFY'>FY20</td>
                <td class='norm'>Subject 5</td>
                <td class='norm'>Subject 6</td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    <div class="side">
        REPORTING
    </div>
</div>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
Its not exclusively the rotation I'm having the difficulty with, but the alignment of the "Reporting" Div to the right side of the table, and when that is rotated, how it throws the alignment out. All suggestions so far have been just how to rotate a div, which is fine, but doesn't solve the full problem. I have the div lining up with the right side of the table now, but the text alignment and width is still way off. Here is my most recent code snippet, please run the snippet to see what the current results are compared to the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

```html
<style>
        .container {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: x-large;
            margin: 0;
            color: black;
            padding: 1em 0.5em;
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        .tableCont {
            float:left;
            width:50%;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            font-size: 1em;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

            table td {
                border-radius: 15px;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 100px;
                margin-right:20px;
            }

                table td.colFY {
                    width: 100px;
                    background-color: #887870;
                }

                table td.norm {
                    background-color: #B8B8B8;
                    color: #082860;
                }

        .side {
            float:left;
            background: #B8B8B8;
            padding-top:15%;
            padding-left:10%;
        }

        .vtext {
            
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
            }
    </style>

 <div class='container'>

        <div class="tableCont">
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td class='colFY'>FY18</td>
                    <td class='norm'>Subject 1</td>
                    <td class='norm'>Subject 2</td>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='colFY'>FY19</td>
                    <td class='norm'>Subject 3</td>
                    <td class='norm'>Subject 4</td>
                    <!--<td rowspan="1" class="vtext side">REPORTING</td>-->

                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='colFY'>FY20</td>
                    <td class='norm'>Subject 5</td>
                    <td class='norm'>Subject 6</td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="side vtext">
            REPORTING
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

****
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
```

You can check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use css rotation [CSS3 2D Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp):

```
.side {
  background: #B8B8B8;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zajubzm/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

and

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

```css
.vtext {
  
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" class="vtext">REPORTING</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FY18</td>
    <td>Subject 1</td>
    <td>Subject 2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>FY18</td>
    <td>Subject 1</td>
    <td>Subject 2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>FY18</td>
    <td>Subject 1</td>
    <td>Subject 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```